# Sitecore Media Library - missing Alt Text

Tags: sitecore, alt, sitecore-media-library

I am using Sitecore 9.0. There used to be an option while uploading an image to use either the normal "File Upload" or "Upload File Advanced" to enter the *Alt Text* before uploading the image in the upload dialog box itself. It is now missing.

Can someone guide me on how to get it back? The *Alt Text* option used to be visible in the red highlighted box below.

[image: Upload file dialog]

Answer (score 3):

The File Upload dialog allowing you to set the *Alternate text* is based on a Flash uploader. There is an *Upload.Classic* setting in *Sitecore.config* indicating whether the uploading runs in classic (no Flash) mode or not; the default value is `false`, so that the Flash uploader should be used by default:

```
<setting name="Upload.Classic" value="false" />
```

But, for security reason, Flash is not enabled by default in modern browsers, therefore, if you want to use the Flash uploader you also have to allow it in your browser.

How to allow Flash in Google Chrome browser?

1. To the left of the web address, click *Lock* or *Info* icons;
2. Then at the bottom on the popup, click *Site Settings*;
3. In the new tab, to the right of *"Flash"*, click the *Down* arrow and then select *Allow*;
4. Go back to the site and reload the page;

Note, that Sitecore client interface issues a persistent ***sc_fv*** cookie where it stores the Flash status, its value for the blocked Flash mode is '0.0.0'. Therefore, once the Flash is allowed in your browser you need to delete the ***sc_fv*** cookie to force the Flash status check.

So, summing all up, if you wish to use the Flash file uploader you have to complete 3 simple steps below:

1. Make sure that *Upload.Classic* setting is set to `false` in *Sitecore.config*;
2. Allow Flash in your browser;
3. Delete ***sc_fv*** cookie.

And you will get the *Alternate text* field back in the Upload File dialog:
[image]